# dnsmasq; log querying process

Tags: macos, dnsmasq, strace

I'm running dnsmasq in development and found that something on my laptop is putting forward queries for randomly generated domain names. Hence I'd like to display the PID/`lsof -p` output of the process when it queries.

How can I do this? I'd be up to using strace or similar. On OS X, not linux.

Comment: could it be Chrome?.. Chrome creates random queries to test the DNS setup iirc.

Comment: I didn't know it did; I was indeed running Chromium.